what the differnce between keymap: curve and curves?
no question about the Keymap: Curve.
what the Keymap: Curves responsible for?
thank you


Its for when you're editing a Curves object, in Edit Mode. With a mesh object selected and active, if you press Shift+A > Curve > Empty Hair or Fur it adds a curves object and several Geometry nodes trees that work as the hair system. The alternative is just for regular spline-type curves.

@Jakemoyo that seems to be a complete answer. Please post it as such.

The Curve keymap pertains to traditional curve objects in the 3D view, like Bezier, NURBS, and Paths in both Object and Edit Mode. The are usually edited on a point by point basis, possibly using snapping and manually controlling handles individually.
The Curves keymap is specific for the new Hair type curves, which are typically associated with a base mesh and use geometry nodes based interpolation to populate the mesh surface based on a few guide curves. They are typically edited using bulk operations like combing, bending, braiding that affect multiple curves en mass.
